# How can I remove a function that was called earlier when a certain condition was met?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I would like a function to be called only when the browser is greater than `640px`. So far I have the following, which successfully loads the function when the screen width is greater than `640px` but the problem I'm facing, is that when the browser width goes back under `640px`, the function is still active. In my particular scenario I do not want the function loading on smaller displays, hence why I'm trying to call it using the below code. How can I somehow remove/destroy the function when the browser is resized back under `640px`?

```
<script> 
    function someFunction() {
     // .. does something when the browser width is greater than 640px
    }

    (function($){
          //detect the width on page load and load the function
          $(document).ready(function(){
             var current_width = $(window).width();

               if(current_width > 640){
                 someFunction();
               }
            }
          });

          //update the width value when the browser is resized
          $(window).resize(function(){
            var current_width = $(window).width();

            if(current_width > 640){
                someFunction(); 
            }

          });

        })(jQuery);
</script>
```

Here's a full jsFiddle example of what I have so far as per the help I have had so far. http://jsfiddle.net/7Dqna/26/

I'm implementing a sticky sidebar that scrolls with the page when it hits the top of the browser but I am trying to turn off the function at smaller screen sizes (think mobile).

It works when the page is refreshed, but if you make the browser window bigger, then smaller (less than 400px in the jsFiddle example) the menu still is still given the CSS by the function. So I guess it's not picking up the resize thingie.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $(window).on('load resize', ifWidth);

     function ifWidth() {  
         var W = $(window).width();
         if(W > 640){
             someFunction();
             $(window).off('resize', ifWidth);
         }
     }

     function someFunction() {
         // .. does something when the browser width is greater than 640px
     }
});
​
```

Comment: Thanks, I believe this has gotten me closer. I've pasted the working example at http://jsfiddle.net/7Dqna/26/. What I was trying to do was disable the JS function for the sticky sidebar, as you can see in the example. It works when the page is refreshed, but if you make the browser window bigger, then smaller (less than 400px in the jsFiddle example) the menu still has the css given to it by the function.

Comment: @Andrew - Not sure I get it, my impression was that you were trying to remove the resize handler after the window had been resized over a certain width. Is this what you are really trying to do : [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/7Dqna/27/)

Comment: Thank you. Your jsFiddle example is what I was trying to achieve. Apologies for not explaining it correctly. I thought the best way to tackle my problem was to somehow remove the moveNav function altogether under a certain browser width. The reason I wanted to do this is because I didn't want the navigation to inherit the moveNav function on smaller displays and mobiles, and only on desktop sized resolutions. I've modified your else condition to simply set the position back to relative. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

why not just put the width size check into the function and return from it if the size is not at least 640? e.g.

```
var jWindow = $(window);

jWindow.resize( function() {
    someFunction();
});

function someFunction(){
    if ( jWindow.width() < 640 ){ return; }
    // do stuff here
}
```

alternatively, you could do `window.someFunction = function(){ return; }`

Comment: If he did some DOM changes and events listening in `someFunction` it is might not be enough...

Comment: @gdoron, then set a global flag and check it in every listener

Comment: That's right, and that is my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9449727/601179) ... **=)**

Answer (score 0):

I can think on two ways to do it:

1. Create an `unSomeFunction` that will reverse `someFunction` work.
2. Inside `someFunction` check a boolean flag to know what's the size of the window.

Answer (score 0):

It is happening because of `$(window).resize()` handler. If you just want this logic to be executed only on page load then just execute it on document ready and remove the `$(window).resize()` handler.